# unable to start tomcat with startup.sh

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

Hi I just installed tomcat on UBUNTU 12.04 LTS . I am using the script "**sh catalina.sh run**" command to start up the server . When i try to execute the script **sh startup.sh** or the **catalina.sh start** , the server does not start up . I get the below output and the script stops . I tried putting echo statements but could not figure out where the issue is.

*Output after executing the script:*

```
$ sh startup.sh

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

niranjan@niranjan-VirtualBox:/media/Data/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin$
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try checking your ports and try again. Other programs may be using the port 80 especially. Also if your Skype is running, close it or change its port as well.

Regards

kizito

Comment: Its not an issue with the ports . I have already changed the ports , When i run the Catalina.sh using "sh catalina.sh run" the server is up . So I dont think there is an issue with port binding

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the **JAVA_HOME** variable properly configured?
2. What is the output for `java -version` command?

Check the log files. To clarify the cause, you may set the logging level to the fullest.

Answer (score -1):

when i run using the startup.sh or the catalina.sh start (argument as start)  the output/log gets redirected to prevent this i had to use catalina.sh run ( argument as run) .